# ReactiveMongo: No mongo-async-driver configuration found

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I am starting out with ReactiveMongo, and while log level is set to `debug`

I see the following print to the log:

> ```
> application - ReactiveMongoApi starting...
> reactivemongo.api.MongoDriver - No mongo-async-driver configuration found
> application - ReactiveMongoApi successfully configured with DB 'mydb'! Servers:
>     [mongodb:27017]
> ```

The question is: Do I have anything to be concerened about with that no async driver found? and why is it beeing printed.

Comment: That's just some debug, that's why the `DEBUG` level is used

Answer (score 4):

The ReactiveMongo package is looking for some configuration. it doesn't mean that the driver operation will not be async because no configuration was found.

To get rid of the error, you can add configuration in the application.conf

Example:

> ```
> mongo-async-driver {
>     akka {
>         loggers = [ "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger" ]
>         loglevel = DEBUG
>     }
> }
> ```